# Is it guaranteed that std::vector each allocated memory with allocate function, will also deallocate at once, with single deallocate call?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, stl, allocator

I'm writing custom allocator for std::vector, and want to know how std::vector uses specified allocator? May it allocate memory for 5 objects, and then deallocate memory partially, for example at first 2 element, then 3 elements... (I don't see any reason not to do so).

Is there anything mentioned about it in standard? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: This is all implementation defined. Usually, once `vector.size() == vector.capacity()` and you insert something it's doubling it's capacity.

Comment: A std::vector holds a single continuous block of memory (why do you care, anyway?)

Comment: How can I write an allocator is I don't know how exactly it'll be called?

Comment: Say, memory allocated with N size I'm keeping in separate place, and if it'll deallocate N/2 and N/2 separately, I'll deallocate from wrong place.

Comment: You have to write an allocator subject to the constraint that you don't know exactly how it will be called. Sounds like to me you need to write your own *container* class from scratch, for some reason.

Comment: So there is nothing mentioned about it in the standard?

Comment: The good answer by @legends2k tells you what the standard states.

Comment: std::vector and std::allocator (or your allocator) are loosely coupled. The allocator does not know any container (use case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it guaranteed that `std::vector` each allocated memory with allocate function, will also deallocate at once, with single deallocate call?

Yes.  The prototype of `std::allocator::deallocate` is

```
void deallocate( pointer p, size_type n );
```

> May it allocate memory for 5 objects, and then deallocate memory partially, for example at first 2 element, then 3 elements... (I don't see any reason not to do so).

But `n` cannot be different from what was passed earlier to the matching `allocate` function, as [explained in the spec.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator/deallocate):

> Deallocates the storage referenced by the pointer p, which must be a pointer obtained by an earlier call to allocate(). The argument n must be equal to the first argument of the call to allocate() that originally produced p.

Basically, the arguments to `deallocate` are

1. whatever was returned by `allocate`
2. the corresponding `n` that was passed for getting it